# How do I determine a gmail message is flagged as important (in the important folder) via IMAP

Tags: c#, gmail, imap

I am accessing my gmail account via IMAP, in C#.

In addition to the "Starred" folder, there is also the "Important" folder. Messages are added to this folder if you click the little yellow tag, or automatically based on google's magic.

As I am viewing items (in the inbox, or other folders) I would like to know if it is marked as important.

But this information does not appear in the Labels content, nor in the Flags (unread etc) content.

Is there any way to get the "Important" label to show up like the other labels on a message? Or some other way to examine the message to see it is important?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but [`X-GM-LABELS`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_gmail_labels_x-gm-labels) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: The important label is not included in that collection. (I note that the "important" label also doesn't actually show up in gmail anymore in the list of labels applied to the message, which is perhaps the root cause.

Comment: Is there a label called Flagged? or perhaps is the \Flagged flag set?